# HTML Response compared with old html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a response from an AJAX request using jQuery returned as 'response'

I need to compare it with old HTML. If it is different it will just do some css.

The problem is it detects a different change everytime even when there is no difference and there is a continueous loop which makes my animation on css repeat itself.

```
var oldHTML = $("#container").html();
$.ajax({  
        url: "ajax/log.php",  
        cache: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(response){
            if(oldHTML != response)
            {
                $("#container").css({"border":"1px solid red"}),
                $("#container").animate({"border":"none"}); 
            }
        }
```

It does not always detect a change or no change. It also loops the animation bit.

Comment: Please post the comparison code.

Answer (score 1):

There might be alterations to the html when its being appended to the DOM. I would store the HTML into the element as a data object as-is to keep a copy of it.

Such as

```
   // get the saved response, if any, that was saved on the last ajax request
    var oldHTML = $("#container").data('oldHTML');
    $.ajax({  
                    url: "ajax/log.php",  
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(response){
                      if(oldHTML != response){
                         $("#container").css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                         $("#container").animate({"border":"none"}); }
                        // assign the original server response to oldHTML
                         $("#container").data('oldHTML', response);
                        // shove response into the DOM
                         $("#container").html(response);
                       }else {
                          // i guess you're doing nothing here?
                      }
           });
```

or someting similar, hopefully that conveys the idea

Comment: How does <pre>var oldHTML = $("#container").data('oldHTML');</pre> get the HTML of #container?

Comment: if it's full ajax, then when it is populated (i took a stab at how you're doing it, see the conditional; when it sets the html, it also assigns 'oldHTML' to the original server-returned data) - if #container is set by the server originally, then after you check for the saved data, you could do if(oldHTML == "") { oldHTML = $('#container').html(); } - but it sounds like whenever the ajax request runs for the first time, you want that html in #container, yes? (made some changes to the above code)

Comment: Getting any script errors? (check the lower left corner and make sure its enabled in internet options) - is the whole ajax failing or just the conditional? if it's the whole thing, make sure you're including jquery as text/javascript not application/javascript

Comment: No errors and using text/javascript.

I've changed my script to play sound. It loops on IE and i have the problem that my script is messy:
     if($.data(document.body,'oldHTML') != html){

        $('body').append('<div id="soundContainer"><embed src="alert.mp3" autostart="true" loop="false" volume="100" hidden="true" /></div>'),
        $("#soundContainer").fadeOut(2000, function(){
       $("#soundContainer").remove();            
       });
     }

Comment: I would put the whole source into jsbin.com so we can have a look. There must be a different way to go about tracking changes to the body element, though - that seems quite intensive of an 'if' statement, lol..

Comment: Ah very good xD , embed appears but no settings now lol

And weird is that on IE that if statement loops itself???

Comment: Erm, not sure you understand. Looking in the developer thing in chrome, it shows <embed>. No settings?
And in IE it repeatedly does that appendTo function and remove it etc.

Comment: what is calling "loadLog" - is IE calling _that_ function over and over?

Comment: No no, the script inside if(oldHTML != html) {}

Comment: that should only fire on success, which means the ajax call is being fired multiple times. If you do something each time loadLog() is executing (like a $('#consoleDiv').append('<br />Running function'); call) does it only show the single request with a bunch of ajax returns? Something isn't right here...

Comment: i updated the whole thing with .post to make sure your response is html

Comment: Why .post when we're retrieving info?

Comment: .post is a wrapper for .ajax, just a bit easier to deal with and formats the return data (in this case, html). Either way, ajax/messages.php is being called and the results handled. There is more to your script/page though, such as why you're checking if html is different instead of just flagging a variable when the data is updated. Does the $('#chatbox') get updated by another function? is this by a user? is it a textarea that could use a 'onchange' event instead?

Comment: Still here xD

$('#chatbox')  lists the chat been said

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: We've already tackled how to do a comparison of the html - but if you're using cometchat, you can alter the code yourself (the javascript is 'cometchat/cometchatjs.php' - you can add your own "play sound script" when things happen. In other words, I think you should take a stab at a different way to get the sound to play than comparing the HTML - that there is a simpler, faster, and better way to get your task accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I would rephrase your question to mention jQuery & AJAX -- took me a second to see the tags.

I would use a file comparison such as WinMerge (free) to see what the difference is.

My guess is it might have to do with spacing, in which case you can use a trim function.

Also, if you post your code it would be helpful.